# How to make thrift to work with Angular 2 and webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack, thrift

From a simple Angular 2 + Webpack working project, I'm trying to integrate Apache Thrift by implementing the Thrift's tutorial. I reach a point where everything works except the browser cannot find the Thrift module:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Thrift is not defined
```

The error is thrown from the thrift generated files, `tutorial_types.js`, when it tries to access the thrift module:

```
InvalidOperation = function(args) {
  this.whatOp = null;
  this.why = null;
  if (args) {
    if (args.whatOp !== undefined && args.whatOp !== null) {
      this.whatOp = args.whatOp;
    }
    if (args.why !== undefined && args.why !== null) {
      this.why = args.why;
    }
  }
};
Thrift.inherits(InvalidOperation, Thrift.TException);
```

Angular loads the application, that loads the generated files that try to load Thrift and fail.

The project is available here: https://github.com/osechet/angular-thrift

To test, run:

```
git clone https://github.com/osechet/angular-thrift
cd angular-thrift
npm install
npm gen.thrift
npm start
```

Then open http://localhost:8080/ in a browser.

I checked the files created by Webpack and the thrift module is bundled. What am I missing?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the part of the code that's throwing the error to your question - it's a lot to ask for people to install your project and run it themselves.

Comment: @JoeClay You are right. I added a clarification about it.

Comment: Hm, does Thrift actually get imported *in* the generated file? If not, that's probably why things are failing. You'd need to either figure out a way to get Thrift to generate files with `var Thrift = require("thrift");` at the top, or import it from one of your files and attach it to the global environment (`window.Thrift`).

Comment: @JoeClay Thanks for your comment. It made me find that the js library of Thrift does not export any module. I changed my project to use the browser module of the nodejs library and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JoeClay's remark, I found the problem. The Javascript library provided with Thrift does not export any module and thus isn't properly bundled by Webpack.

I changed my project to use the browser module of the nodejs library provided by Thrift (`thrift/lib/nodejs/lib/thrift/browser.js`). Doing so, I have been able to make the whole application to work.

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :)